# PHP - simple condition with parenthesis

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a stupid question about this condition.

Why when I put parenthesis, the result of the condition changes?

```
$std = new \stdClass();
$std->bool = false;
$resultCond1 = isset($std->bool) and $std->bool == true;
$resultCond2 = (isset($std->bool) and $std->bool == true);

var_dump($resultCond1); // True. 
var_dump($resultCond2); // False.
```

Comment: If you use `&&` instead of `and` then the parentheses won't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is due to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Notice in that table that the assignment operators lie firmly between `and` and `&&`.  Here's what I think is happening:

In the first example, `isset` is returning true and, *prior* to the `and` operation taking place the assignment is happening. After the assignment, the result of the assignment is `and`'ed and the result of that `and` operation is then summarily discarded.

In the second example the parentheses dictate that the assignment happens last and so you get the expected result.

You can see this more clearly if you remove the assignment operation altogether and just dump the result of the operations themselves:

```
var_dump(isset($std->bool) and $std->bool == true);   // bool(false)
var_dump((isset($std->bool) and $std->bool == true)); // bool(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

Both of these conditions are not outputting same result because of operator precedence.

1) For the first one - `isset($std->bool)` returns true, after that it will check `and $std->bool`, lastly it will compare that result with `true`

2) For the second one - it will check `isset($std->bool)` and `$std->bool == true` separately. Then compare both of these result.

Second one is more convenient & cleaner way to accomplish this type of work.